# Add local variable to JShell evaluation context

Tags: java, reflection, jshell

I'm using `jdk.jshell.JShell` to [evaluate Java code programmatically](https://hachyderm.io/@zdimension/109458143921379121) and I'd like to add a local variable to the active evaluation context, so the value is useable in the shell.

I'm instantiating the JShell with a DirectExecutionControl, so it runs on the same JVM as the main code. I've spent quite a lot of time stepping through the source code of the JDK trying to see where I could plug myself, but it's quite opaque; simply getting an `Object` result out of `eval(...)` instead of a `String` required a number of hacks (Oracle, why?).

The answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54952810/jshell-access-to-variables-defined-outside-of-jshell-instance) seems to suggest that this is not possible, without justification, but I'm too deep into this to accept that.

Ideas I have thought about:

```
- creating a class dynamically, with a field corresponding to the variable I want to add, and `import static`ing that class into the JShell (but I don't know how to dynamically add an import either)
- trying to find one of the internal auto-generated classes JShell is using to store the variables, and replacing them using arcane reflection magic
```